# Windows Phone class library localized resources not working

Tags: dll, localization, windows-phone, class-library

I have a Windows Phone class library with a resources (.resx) file. I have a reference to the class library from an actual Windows Phone Application project. Everything works well when I reference the library project in the solution, but when I add a reference to the actual assembly (.dll) file then localization stops working and the Windows Phone Application just uses the default locale when navigating to the pages declared in the library assembly. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. When you reference a Windows Phone library assembly (the .dll file itself, not its project within the same solution), you have to make sure that its resource folders are in the same directory as the assembly. That is, if your library is localized in Spanish for example, besides copying the .dll file from your bin folder, you must also copy the 'es' folder to the same directory.

Comment: Do I have to add a reference to it? Because I get "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project" if I try. And it doesn't work when simply copying the folder.

Comment: @Naning you're getting that error because the library you're referencing targets a higher version of Windows Phone than the project referencing it. So, let's say the library targets Windows Phone 8 and up,  your project in Visual Studio cannot target Windows Phone 7 or 7.5, it has to target Windows Phone 8 and up also.

Comment: @Naning Also, if you're downloading the .dll from the internet, there is a glitch in Visual Studio that prevents you from adding it by showing you that error. You have to right click the assembly in the file system, click properties, unblock it, and click apply and accept.